# What's the best money option for US travelling?

Tags: usa, money

My friends and I are going on a road trip in the US. We're wondering what kind of money we should take, be it a credit card, debit card, pre-paid card or just cash. We're going for two weeks. Does anyone has any experience what works the best in the US and how to avoid hidden bank transactions/ATM fees?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  There are several questions related to yours: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/do-all-american-atms-charge-an-extra-fee-for-cash-withdrawals-on-a-foreign-card, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25899/how-do-i-ensure-that-my-atm-card-will-work-while-traveling-within-the-us .  In addtion "best" is very subjective and generally frowned upon without specific criteria attached as per the [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Answering this requires additional details from where are you coming from. For example, from Brazil, there are some tax when you load your Visa Travel Money with cash. your country might have different rules.

Comment: this great answer : http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/20783/4584  also helps ;)

Answer (score 7):

When I've travelled in the USA, I take (in order of preference)

- Credit Card
- Cash
- ATM Card

I found that all places accepted foreign Credit Cards without a problem.  Your credit card provider can inform you of the fees for transactions in the USA.  In addition, your provider will be able to replace your card if it gets lost or stolen.

I used a Visa credit card.

It's worth taking a small amount of cash.  Depending on where you're going, a small pizza restaurant won't take a card for a $1.99 slice.  Food and drink vending machines often only accept cash.  Buses are also usually cash only. Tipping for personal services (like hotel staff carrying your bags) is usually cash.

Take a small amount of cash - I'd suggest $50 - 100 should be fine for emergencies / sundries.

Finally, take an ATM card and put it somewhere separate from your credit cards and cash.  American ATMs can charge *outrageous* fees for transactions.  Speak to your bank to see how much they charge as well.

In all cases, tell your bank & credit card company when you'll be in the USA so that they don't block your card & leave you stranded.

Comment: Different Credit Cards can also charge different overseas fees, so it can also be worth looking into getting one with lower / no fees before you go (assuming they exist in your country of residency)

Comment: Admittedly this was 10 years ago in 2004, but I once had trouble using a UK Visa card to buy a plane ticket. The airline wouldn't accept it online or by phone, and said the reason was the address, but that I could use it at the airline's desk at an airport. The airport I paid at wasn't involved in the flight I was buying, the difference was that it was a cardholder-present transaction.

Comment: Please dubble check if your card is accepted. My card (Maestro) was only accepted in the big venue's (i.e. Walmart).

Comment: Maestro is hardly accepted anywhere. Even I always carry my primary Visa card and a master card to get some offers. You should be fine with either of those.

Comment: Also, make sure to inform your CC company beforehand, so they expect withdrawals from the correct country.

Comment: I would also strictly avoid the pre-paid card option. Some places won't accept them at all (since your name is not on the card) and in some cases you'll get false rejections if your available balance is too close to the transaction amount, or if you've got reserve amounts that haven't cleared yet.

Comment: Banks used to waive ATM fees for ex-US cards, but now _some_ of them have decided to screw you tourists, too. Depending on which type of ATM card you have, you can ask the issuer which, if any, USA banks will waive the fees.